# Paypal PHP SDK REST is not returning any "success" variable

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I make basic PayPal payment on sandbox, following instructions on official samples here:

- [CreatePaymentUsingPayPal](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html)
- [Execution](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/ExecutePayment.html)

The problem appears when my Execution service is getting request from paypal server. After dumping $_GET variables I can see something like:

```
array:3 [▼
  "paymentId" => "PAY-9HM25571EF136871GLEWZM6A"
  "token" => "EC-6VX65808WU776334M"
  "PayerID" => "2ADP8W2S9ST8Z"
]
```

So there is no variable called "success". If payment ended without success I should get "success": false. I have no idea what is going on and how can I fix  it.

Please for help,

Arthur.

Answer (score 0):

The variable you're looking for is the state. The three possible values: `created`, `approved`, `failed`. [Here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/)'s what the raw json looks like.

```
{
    "id": "PAY-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {},
    "cart": "",
    "transactions": [{}],
    "state": "approved",
    "create_time": "2017-08-14T15:38:12Z",
    "links": [{}]
}
```

If you're creating the payment, to send the buyer to authorize the payment, you'd want state to be created. If you're executing the payment, you want state to be approved.

The $payment and $result objects represent the json responses as objects. Running `$result->getStatus()` should return the status string.

Answer (score 0):

The "success" is not going to come automatically. When you make your initial POST v1/Payments call (Create Payment) you need to include the below

```
$baseUrl = getBaseUrl();
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("$baseUrl/ExecutePayment.php?success=true")
    ->setCancelUrl("$baseUrl/ExecutePayment.php?success=false");
```

check this out [http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html][1]

basically just make sure you specify your success return URL as something like www.mysite.com/successpage.html?success=true . PYPL will append paymentId=PAY67S97196TG1078736LIKMI4Q&token=EC37412549V2519404X&PayerID=DNZQ8C57C7P6Q