# PayPal PHP SDK - Not returning GET variable 'success'

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Using the PayPal PHP SDK I am creating a payment and receiving a JSON response such as the example below which looks valid and contains an authoriztion URL such as:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-5W411607PA915392K

I go to the URL, login, and it redirects me back to my site with the following GET variables:

> paymentId=PAY-67S97196TG1078736LIKMI4Q&token=EC-37412549V2519404X&PayerID=DNZQ8C57C7P6Q

The problem is that according the example here (http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/ExecutePayment.html) I need to check for `$_GET['success']` to see if successful.  However as you can see I did not get that variable in my response, only the three above.

I am using the PayPall PHP SDK located here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK

Here is a link to a similar question: [Paypal PHP SDK REST is not returning any "success" variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267179/paypal-php-sdk-rest-is-not-returning-any-success-variable)

Answer (score 1):

The "success" is not going to come automatically. When you make your initial POST /Payments calls you need to include the below

```
$baseUrl = getBaseUrl();
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("$baseUrl/ExecutePayment.php?success=true")
    ->setCancelUrl("$baseUrl/ExecutePayment.php?success=false");
```

check this out [http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html][1]

basically just make sure you specify your success return URL  as something like www.mysite.com/successpage.html?success=true . PYPL will append 
paymentId=PAY67S97196TG1078736LIKMI4Q&token=EC37412549V2519404X&PayerID=DNZQ8C57C7P6Q

Comment: I m using similar method, using curl PHP.

I m facing issues in receiving get variables on the success page.
Did everything from this. It inserts record & everything but success page it fails cos i m not getting GET variables on success.php

https://www.codexworld.com/paypal-standard-payment-gateway-integration-php/

Comment: any help possible? how to implement in my provided link.